# Function inside Jquery $.ajax callback with params

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a Jquery ajax function

```
t.doPostCall=function(url,data,ResponseHandler){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data:data,
        success: function(response){
            ResponseHandler(response);
        },
        error:function(response){
            ResponseHandler(response.responseJSON);
        },
        dataType: "json"
    });
};
```

I want to pass parameter to ResponseHandler(response,function(){}) and execute that function depending on response.

```
ResponseHandler(response,fn){
   if(response.check!=null){
     fn();
   }
}
```

Is it possible to do this without adding the fn to **doPostCall**.

Comment: Yes, I will post example, you may need to use a que depending on usage. Can't you just call it as normal?

Comment: @Casey Please post it. Thanks!!!

Comment: Also, you do not need to use th t.doPostCall=function() if you don't want to. You can just call the $.ajax() inline.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you are reffering to.

Comment: I am exposing this as a Wrapper so